# How to make images with links line up?

Tags: html, css

I have three social media images (Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn) which I want to embedded on to my home page with links within, I have got the CSS for each logo but I just can't get them to line up (three in a row, centralized), any advises?

CSS:

```
.twitter-logo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url("https://www.sites.com/Twitter_web.png") no-repeat;
  float: left;
}

.facebook-logo {
  width: 39px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url("https://www.sites.com/Facebook_web.png")no-repeat;
  float: left;
}

.linkedin-logo {
  width: 41px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url("https://www.sites.com/LinkedIn_web.png") no-repeat;
  float: left;
}

.follow-us-three {
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="follow-us-three">
  <a class="facebook-logo" href="link"></a>
  <a class="twitter-logo" href="link"></a>
  <a class="linkedin-logo" href="link"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note... look at using CSS Sprites: https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 1):

Try This, I think by three in a row and centralized you mean you want to set the size of the background as your link's size.

I have just added background-size:cover;

```
   .twitter-logo {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background: url("download.png") no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        float: left;
    }

    .facebook-logo {
        width: 39px;
        height: 40px;
        background: url("download.png") no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        float: left;
    }

    .linkedin-logo {
        width: 41px;
        height: 40px;
        background: url("download.png") no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        float: left;
    }

    .follow-us-three {
        margin: 10px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
        border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try below css code.

```css
.linkedin-logo,.twitter-logo,.facebook-logo{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;  
  background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/666407537084796928/YBGgi9BO.png");
  float: left;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
}

.follow-us-three {
  margin: 10px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="follow-us-three">
  <a class="facebook-logo" href="link"></a>
  <a class="twitter-logo" href="link"></a>
  <a class="linkedin-logo" href="link"></a>
</div>
```

I just added "background-position: center;  background-size: 40px 40px;" so that you can see the icons in proper way.

Comment: Some explanation of what you have done and why would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues...

1. Anchor elements `<a>` default display is `inline`
2. You need to restore document flow with clear fix

You can easily change the display of your anchor tags by setting the display property to `display: block` or `display: inline-block`. This will allow these element to have a width and a height.

Because you are floating the elements you need to restore document flow by applying a clear fix to the parent element.

Here is an example...

https://jsfiddle.net/kennethcss/5jzqyhjh/

Also note, that you could remove the floats and just change the display property to `inline-block` and get the same result but either is valid.

**Additional reading:**

- [CSS Display Property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)
- [Clear Fix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) and [Floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: Note when you float an element it becomes a block: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/#what-you-should-know-about-floats

Comment: Just the mere presence of a float does not change the default display of the element being floated, so in the case of inline elements that you want to display as block, you have to apply that property in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of reducing replicated code I have done the following:

- Created a generic `logo` class
- Used CSS sprites to position the image.
- Changed from float to `inline-block` to center the links easier and more efficiently.

**NOTE** Don't use the sprite as provided, use your own. Also note `inline-block` introduces about a px space between the links.

```css
.follow-us-three .logo
{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url("http://67.media.tumblr.com/b2336d673e315081b6d657f8258c313d/tumblr_mv98xzSiJu1qhori9o1_500.jpg") no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
}

.logo.twitter {
   background-position:-120px 0px ;
}

.logo.facebook {
  background-position:-80px 0px ;
}

.logo.linkedin {
   background-position:-325px 0px ;
}

.follow-us-three {
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="follow-us-three">
  <a class="logo facebook" href="link"></a>
  <a class="logo twitter" href="link"></a>
  <a class="logo linkedin" href="link"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What i would like to suggest is use `<img>` tag inside your `<a>` tags and avoid using `background` property of `link` like

CSS:

```
   .twitter-logo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.facebook-logo {
  width: 39px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
margin-left:10px;
}

.linkedin-logo {
  width: 41px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
margin-left:10px;
}

.follow-us-three {
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="follow-us-three">
  <a  href="link"><img class="twitter-logo" src="https://g.twimg.com/Twitter_logo_blue.png"></img></a>
  <a  href="link"><img class="facebook-logo" src="https://www.facebookbrand.com/img/fb-art.jpg"/></a>
  <a  href="link"><img class="linkedin-logo" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/linkedin-logo-3.png"/></a>
</div>
```

Mention whatever you like to mention in `href` attribute of your links and also Your links were not working so added new links.Hope it helps.

Another tip i would like to give you is start learning bootstrap because it has pre-defined icons for sites like facebook,twitter and thore icons are very good looking and easy to use.